# Java generic classes, how to make an instance

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class structure:

```
public abstract class Generic<T extends SuperClass>

public class SuperGeneric<T extends SuperClass & SomeInterface> 
    extends Generic<T>
```

Now I want to make an instance of `SuperGeneric` covering all possible classes. I tried it like this:

```
Generic<? extends SuperClass & SomeInterface> myGeneric 
    = new SuperGeneric<? extends SuperClass & SomeInterface>();
```

Now this doesn't seem to work.
On `Generic` it gives the following error: `Incorrect number of arguments for type Generic<T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <? extends SuperClass, SomeInterface>`.

And on the `new SuperGeneric` I get a similar error: `Incorrect number of arguments for type SuperGeneric<T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <? extends SuperClass, SomeInterface>`.

Any idea how to correctly create instances of this `SuperGeneric`?

The idea is that I have 2 different classes that satisfy the `extends SuperClass & SomeInterface` condition but those cannot be generalized by one type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to instantiate a generic class, you need to provide the concrete type. You said there are two classes that fulfill the constraint. Say these are `Type1` and `Type2`.

Then you should be able to do:

```
Generic<Type1> myGeneric1 = new SuperGeneric<Type1>();
```

and

```
Generic<Type2> myGeneric2 = new SuperGeneric<Type2>();
```

The wildcards are used only for declaration. They mean: You can put any type here (that fulfills the given constraints)

Comment: So where are wildcards used then? In method arguments and return-types?

Comment: @stevenroose see my last sentence

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiate you need to provide a type for the compiler to fill in.

Comment: So where are wildcards used then? In method arguments and return-types?

Comment: The wildcards describe what T can be. But you actually need to provide something for T.

Comment: You are conflating Class Literals and other Generics features.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html - This is the oracle tutorial

Comment: @nsfyn55 I find Java syntax confusing too. Whereas in C# you put the type constraints on separate clause(in `where`); in Java you put the type constraint declaration inside the generics declaration (`Generic<T extends ClassNameHere>`), hence your confusion on how to instantiate it. Having said that, when you instantiate(be it Java or C#), they are very simple, same syntax(i.e. `Generic<SomeClass> x = new SuperGeneric<SomeClass>()`), see my comparison at http://www.anicehumble.com/2012/05/c-said-java-said-constraining-generics.html